# DateTimeParseException on Java 11 but works on Java 10

Tags: java-time, java-11

The following testcase runs perfectly under Java 10:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().
          appendPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").
          toFormatter();
        Instant result = dateFormatter.parse("Sat, 29 Sep 2018 20:49:02 GMT", Instant::from);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

but under Java 11 I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sat, 29 Sep 2018 20:49:02 GMT' could not be parsed at index 0
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
        at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

What's going on?

**UPDATE**: Replacing `toFormatter()` with `toFormatter(Locale.US)` fixes the problem. I am guessing this issue is related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206980. This issue is marked as fixed in Java 11 build 23 but I am running

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

Shouldn't this be fixed in this version?

**UPDATE2**: If you are unable to reproduce the problem, try replacing `toFormatter()` with `toFormatter(Locale.CANADA)`.

Comment: I tested your code [using JDK 11 downloaded from Oracle's web site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html) and it worked fine for me. I am using Windows 10, and downloaded the _zip_ file rather than the _exe_ file.

Comment: Are both tests run on the same computer? What is Java’s default locale? Is it the same for your Java 10 and your Java 11?

Comment: @skomisa The default locale is CANADA. If you pass `Locale.CANADA` into the `toFormatter()` you should see the problem.

Comment: @Gili Yes I now see the problem, and the `DateTimeParseException` occurs even if I use **-source 10** under JDK 11. The code runs fine using JDK 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`

Your date-time string is in [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)/[RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) format. Instead of building your own formatter use the built-in [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME):

```
    Instant result = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
            .parse("Sat, 29 Sep 2018 20:49:02 GMT", Instant::from);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Output is:

> Result: 2018-09-29T20:49:02Z

This RFC 1123 formatter is always in English, as required by the RFC specification. I even tried setting my default locale to [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH), and the code still worked.

### What went wrong in your code?

In Java 11 Java expects that the abbreviations for day of week and for month are written with a dot in `Locale.CANADA`: `Sat.` and `Sep.` rather than `Sat` and `Sep`. In Java 10 they are expected without dots, so here parsing works. The difference probably lies in different versions of CLDR data and can hardly be considered a bug in any of the mentioned Java versions. Since Java 9 CLDR has been the default locale data in Java — including what day and month abbreviations look like in different locales.

Demonstration: Using your formatter, but modifying it to use `Locale.CANADA` as you said:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().
            appendPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").
            toFormatter(Locale.CANADA);
    System.out.println("Sample: " + ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"))
            .format(dateFormatter));
```

Running on Java 10.0.2 this printed no dots:

> Sample: Sun, 30 Sep 2018 10:39:28 EDT

And on Java 11 build 11+28:

> Sample: Sun., 30 Sep. 2018 10:50:29 EDT

So I believe that the behaviour has nothing to do with the bug report you linked to.

### Links

- [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)
- [CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository home page](http://cldr.unicode.org)
- [JDK Bug System: DateTimeFormatter throws parsing a valid string depending on the locale](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206980)

Comment: If I replace `toFormatter()` with `toFormatter(Locale.CANADA)` and run under Java 10 and 11 I see the code running under Java 10 but failing under Java 11.

Comment: I believe your answer/comments contain a typo. You wrote RFC 1134 but in the code the enum is for RFC 1123. The number is different.

Comment: Even more than once, @Gili. Corrected. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Just to confirm that using `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` also fixes the issue for me.

Comment: Oracle came to the same conclusion: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211321. Thank you.