# Using Jackson JsonFormat pattern for custom date string

Tags: java, json, jackson

**Summary**

I am attempting to parse dates such as `25/Sep/17` hence the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) annotation seems to be `@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MMM/yy")`. However, when I try to parse this, I get an InvalidFormatException where the essence is (full exception below after example):

```
Text '25/Sep/17' could not be parsed at index 3
```

What is wrong with my date format string? I can't see any issues. It looks like it doesn't like the `Sep` paired with `MMM`.

I am using Amazon Corretto Java version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS

**Example to reproduce**

```
package example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class HelloMapperApp {
  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MAPPER.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    try {
      Example example = MAPPER.readValue("{ \"name\": \"example\", \"date\": \"25/Sep/17\"", Example.class);
      System.out.println("Deserialised is: " + example);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse JSON: " + e);
    }
  }

  static class Example {
    @JsonProperty
    String name;
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MMM/yy")
    LocalDate date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("name: %s%ndate: %s", name, date);
    }
  }
}
```

**Full Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not parse JSON: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
Cannot deserialize value of type 
`java.time.LocalDate` from String "25/Sep/17": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: 
(java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '25/Sep/17' could not be parsed at index 3
 at [Source: (String)"{ "name": "example", "date": "25/Sep/17""; line: 1, column: 30] (through reference chain: example.HelloMapperApp$Example["date"])
        at example.HelloMapperApp.main(HelloMapperApp.java:19)
```

Comment: I just tried that with the usual ```java.time``` stuff and this pattern works with the given input.

Comment: Since it works for you this gave me an idea. I tried the above example in Java 8 and it worked fine. However in Java 11 it fails with the above error. So it seems *Java 11* specific. At least the Corretto JDK 11 does not work with the above example. If you have time/inclination could you share which Java version you tried with?

Comment: I've used Java 11.0.3 (Oracle). I'm having a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson) right now. Maybe this is something. Try out ```@JsonFormat(locale = "en", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MMM/yy")```.

Comment: Ah that works so, in this case anyway, having the `locale = "en"` is probably key. I could leave off the shape and just use `@JsonFormat(locale = "en", pattern = "dd/MMM/yy")` and it worked. A previous answer, since deleted, suggested using `LLL` since it is a local date. So using `dd/LLL/yy` is also working when specifying locale.

Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the case that the given input has a wrong format for the locale used by the formatter. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572726/datetimeparseexception-on-java-11-but-works-on-java-10) is a similar post where someone had a problem with `Sep` where the formatter expected `Sep.` for `Locale.CANADA`.

[Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson) you can check out how to set the locale for the formatter. E.g.:

```java
@JsonFormat(locale = "en", pattern = "dd/MMM/yy")
```

---

FYI: You don't need to use `LLL` for months as a text. Have a look on [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

> Number/Text: If the count of pattern letters is 3 or greater, use the Text rules above. Otherwise use the Number rules above.

When you use `MMM`, i.e. three times `M`, the formatter will implicitly use the text format.